# Aggregation with Group By date in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark, aggregation

I have an RDD containing a timestamp named **time** of type long:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to group by value1, value2 and time as YYYY-MM-DD. I tried to group by cast(time as Date) but then I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.21] failure: ``DECIMAL'' expected but identifier Date found
```

Does that mean there is not way to group by a date? I even tried to add another level of casting to have it as a String:

```
cast(cast(time as Date) as String)
```

Which returns the same error.

I've read that I could use probably aggregateByKey on the RDD but I don't understand how to use it for a few columns and convert that long to a YYYY-MM-DD String. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this function:

```
def convert( time:Long ) : String = {
  val sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  return sdf.format(new java.util.Date(time))
}
```

And registering it into the sqlContext like this:

```
sqlContext.registerFunction("convert", convert _)
```

Then I could finally group by date:

```sql
select * from table convert(time)
```

Comment: Note that for newer versions of Spark, registerFunction should be changed to sqlContext.udf.register("convert", convert _)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Spark 1.4.0 and since 1.2.0 `DATE` appears to be present in the Spark SQL API ([SPARK-2562](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2562)). `DATE` should allow you to group by the time as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I also have a similar data structure, where my `created_on` is analogous to your `time` field.

```
root
|-- id: long (nullable = true)
|-- value1: long (nullable = true)
|-- created_on: long (nullable = true)
```

I solved it using `FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on,'YYYY-MM-dd')` and works well:

```
val countQuery = "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on,'YYYY-MM-dd') as `date_created`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM user GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on,'YYYY-MM-dd')"
```

From here on you can do the normal operations, execute the query into a dataframe and so on.

`FROM_UNIXTIME` worked probably because I have Hive included in my Spark installation and it's a [Hive UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF). However it will be included as part of the Spark SQL native syntax in future releases ([SPARK-8175](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8175)).

Comment: [SPARK-8175](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8175) is now resolved and will be in Spark 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you meant/needed but I've felt the same struggle-ness dealing with date/timestamp in spark-sql and the only thing I came up with was casting string in timestamp since it seems impossible (to me) having Date type in spark-sql.

Anyway, this is my code to accomplish something similar (Long in place of String) to your need (maybe):

```
  val mySQL = sqlContext.sql("select cast(yourLong as timestamp) as time_cast" +
"                                    ,count(1) total "+
"                               from logs" +
"                              group by cast(yourLong as timestamp)" 
)
val result= mySQL.map(x=>(x(0).toString,x(1).toString))
```

and the output is something like this:

```
(2009-12-18 10:09:28.0,7)
(2009-12-18 05:55:14.0,1)
(2009-12-18 16:02:50.0,2)
(2009-12-18 09:32:32.0,2)
```

Could this be useful for you as well even though I'm using timestamp and not Date?

Hope it could help

FF

EDIT:
in order to test a "single-cast" from Long to Timestamp I've tried this simple change:

```
      val mySQL = sqlContext.sql("select cast(1430838439 as timestamp) as time_cast" +
"                                    ,count(1) total "+
"                               from logs" +
"                              group by cast(1430838439 as timestamp)" 
)
val result= mySQL.map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))
```

and all worked fine with the result:

```
(1970-01-17 14:27:18.439,4)  // 4 because I have 4 rows in my table
```

Comment: Thank you, really instructive but my field is of type long which is a timestamp so it doesn't fit exactly... I need to convert it first

Comment: I've tried to "single cast" long to timestamp inside spark-sql and I haven't noticed any problem

Comment: I've just edited my answer with a simple extra example using a Long type inside my query

Comment: if you're still dealing with this problem, could you please post your code in order to understand what gives you that error?

Comment: Grouping by the timestamp works but brings absolutely no grouping because well, the timestamp of every row is different. I solved this by turning the long to a string of format yyyy-MM-dd and grouping then on that.