# Is it possible to group by timestamp in hour, day, weeks.. in select Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I see spark can do this by UDF.

[Aggregation with Group By date in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052937/aggregation-with-group-by-date-in-spark-sql)

Is it possible for Cassandra to do this?

Comment: Cassandra 3.0 will come with UDF as well http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0/.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open ticket to implement this ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9778 ), but at this time, it is not possible.